# php firebase-realtime-database connection

Tags: php, firebase-realtime-database

i have got a php script for connect php to firebase realtime database.I can run the script successfully from the command line, but when I try it from a web browser(on my host), it doesn't work.
`

```
<?php
require_once ('./vendor/autoload.php');
use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount;
class Users{

protected $database;
protected $dbname = 'users';
public function __construct(){
$acc = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__ . '/my_json_file');
$firebase = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount($acc)->create();
$this->database = $firebase->getDatabase();
}
public function get(int $userID = NULL){
    if (empty($userID) || !isset($userID)) { return FALSE; }
    if($this->database->getReference($this->dbname)->getSnapshot()->hasChild($userID)){
        return $this->database->getReference($this->dbname)->getChild($userID)->getValue();
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
public function insert(array $data) {
    if (empty($data) || !isset($data)) { return FALSE; }
    foreach ($data as $key => $value){
        $this->database->getReference()->getChild($this->dbname)->getChild($key)->set($value);
    }
    return TRUE;
}
public function delete(int $userID) {
    if (empty($userID) || !isset($userID)) { return FALSE; }
    if ($this->database->getReference($this->dbname)->getSnapshot()->hasChild($userID)){
        $this->database->getReference($this->dbname)->getChild($userID)->remove();
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
}
$users = new Users();

var_dump($users->insert([
    'name' => 'Harry',
]));
```

`
i am working on phpstorm.
When i ran "php Users.php" on terminal output was "bool(true)" but when uploaded ftp and ran on http://mydomain/Firebase_php_NurSedaGuler/Users.php came just white screen.

Comment: Whats error log say? Enable error reporting in the file too

Comment: [06-Jul-2019 16:37:13 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unsupported declare 'strict_types' in /home/mustafamertyurek/public_html/Firebase_php_NurSedaGuler/vendor/kreait/firebase-php/src/Firebase.php on line 3
[06-Jul-2019 16:37:13 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in /home/mustafamertyurek/public_html/Firebase_php_NurSedaGuler/vendor/kreait/firebase-php/src/Firebase.php on line 52

Comment: [You need PHP 7 for that lib](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/blob/master/composer.json#L19), most likely your host has 5.6 installed

Comment: thanks is there a alternative solution for connection

Comment: You could try an (very) older version like [1.2.2](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/tree/1.2.2) but there is no guarantee it would work. Or see if your host can change php version (some do), or complain then change hosts.